# How to set duration time to two seconds in Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have created a Kineticjs Circle shape, that Im scaling. I start scaling alarmcircle with anim.start();.
Know i wonder if its possible to set a duration time(ex 2 seconds) for the scaling animation.
What I want is to set alarmcircle to scale with a duration of 2 seconds.

```
var period = 2000;

var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    var scale = Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + 0.001;
    alarmcircle.scale({x:scale,y:scale});
}, layer);

anim.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


var period = 2000 ;
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation({
    func: function(frame) {
        if (frame.time >= period ) {
            anim.stop() ;//this will last for 2s and then as soon as the frame time passes 2s it will stop
        } else {
            var scale = Math.sin(frame.time * 2 * Math.PI / period) + 0.001;
            alarmcircle.scale({x:scale,y:scale});
        }
    },
    node: layer
});

anim.start();
</script>
```

Comment: This should give you some idea on how to progress

Comment: I get error: TypeError: c.call is not a function. Do you know what the error is?

Comment: Error:
....splice(e,1);break}},Kinetic.Animation._runFrames=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h...
Kineticjs file:
kinetic.v5.0.0.min.js (line 3)